# Parameter is not valid when loading image into picturebox

Tags: .net

I have a grid with images and selecting each one will load in a picture box

loading the picture like this doesn't work, I get Parameter not valid

```
using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs))
{
    pbImage.Image = image;
}
```

I imagine the image is disposed by the time its displayed.

How can I have it load in the picture box and also prevent it from going 'Out of Memory' ??

Comment: Can you try with `pbImage.Image = new Bitmap(image)`?

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete thanks, that works to get the images to load, but after clicking on a few images, I get out of memory exception

Comment: With the scope you're providing it's not possible to further help you, can you post the code regarding the image click?

Comment: Try disposing the existing pcImage.Image before you set it.

Comment: @LarsTech that works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose current image to prevent the `OutOfMemory` exception and assign the image loaded with a new instance of the `Bitmap` class to preserve the `Image`:

```cs
pbImage.Image?.Dispose();
using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs))
{
    pbImage.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);
}
```